# ggvis filter based on values in multiple columns

Tags: r, ggvis

I've found ggvis to be fantastic when I need to filter by a column, and this works perfectly (uf refers to the unique factors from that column):

```
filter(data$Life.stage %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(uf), selected = uf[[1]])))
```

However, I've been trying to filter by values in 3 different columns and was wondering if that was possible? If I try to do something like this, then it doesn't work.

```
filter(data$[,1:3] %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(c(uf, uf1, uf2), selected = uf[[1]])))
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is `data[,1]` going to be checked against uf, `data[,2]` against uf1 and so on?

Comment: Yes, apologies I should have clarified that. uf, uf1 and uf2 have all the unique factors from those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your data set looks like, and I cannot test the code since you have not provided a reproducible example but if you want to check multiple columns against others you need to use the `&` operator. So, your `filter` function should look something like this:

```
#this compares first column of data against uf and second column of data
#against uf1 and so on..
filter(data[[1]] %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(uf)  , selected =  uf[[1]]) & 
       data[[2]] %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(uf1) , selected = uf1[[1]]) &
       data[[3]] %in% eval(input_checkboxgroup(uf2) , selected = uf2[[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried it before and had trouble getting it to work but just had another go when work got a bit less busy and now it's working :)

Comment: Happy that it has worked :) and you are very welcome !